# Is it possible to accept odata filter as a string rather than odataqueryoptions?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, odata, visual-studio-2017

I have a controller that should accept some type of filter and then forward the request against a web api endpoint such as `http://crmorg/v2/api/`

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions options)
{
//execute GET against http://crmorg/v2/api/options.Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery;
}
```

Instead of doing the above, can I simply accept a string as an odata filter, such as:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(string options)
{
 //
}
```

**Can I pass the odata filter directly into the controller as a string?**

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can do that. But:

- You'd not be able to use the default property mapping
- You'd need need to parse the query string and care for all the possible input variations (think about multi params, sorting, paging, filtering)
- You'd need to cobble the database query and it's options

In short - you rarely need to do that. Try and look at your model and see if there is a way to use the features available in Web API.